# Should I check Host header or ServerName for CSRF defense when serving behind proxies?

Tags: http, proxy, csrf, header

In a CSRF defense based on checking forbidden headers, should I check `Origin`/`Referer` header against the `ServerName` configuration directive, or is it sufficient to simply check against the HTTP `Host` header?

I'm asking because I'm trying to make my application ready for proxies. Load balancers on public networks are one of the many possible use cases, but local SSL/TLS wrapper is more urgent as we need to test WebCrypto API usages in secure contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OWASP Cheatsheets](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#verifying-origin-with-standard-headers), both are fine. I would object checking `X-Forwarded-Host`, as it's not a forbidden header.

You can do the following check, and it will be compatible in most cases: `( $Origin or $Referer ) == ( $Host or %ServerName% )`

As for the load balancer part, if you're considering deploying a commercial CDN for your application, the following configuration may be usable (it's based on Apache HTTPD, other servers would have different config directives):

```
UseCanonicalName on
<VirtualHost *:*>
  ServerName app01.example.com
  ServerAlias app01.source.example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost *:*>
...
```

And configure the DNS servers to resolve `app01.example.com` to the CDN, and point the CDN to `app01.source.example.com`. This way, when an HTTP request arrives at your server, `Origin`/`Referer` will match `ServerName` in your server-side CSRF defense codes.